# Picture from the Internet is smaller than it should be in android

Tags: android, url, inputstream

I would like to load the icon from the Internet. I do it this way:

```
Drawable drawable = null;
                try {
                    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(xml.getBIcon())
                            .getContent();
                    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");

                    drawable = d;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
                }
```

and

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle(title);
                alertDialog.setMessage(text);
                alertDialog.setButton("Install",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                String url = link;
                                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                                context.startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });


                alertDialog.setIcon(drawable);

                alertDialog.show();
            }
```

Unfortunately, the icon is two times lower than it should be. When it is in res folder it is with correct size. What is the reason for this?

Comment: In what dpi folder is the icon placed? My guess is that if you move it to a folder with higher dpi you'll see that both the folder image and the downloaded one are displayed equally. In other words, Android is treating the downloaded image as a higher dpi than the one in the res folder.